# What's itext 7 equivalent to pdfstamper class in itext 5

Tags: .net, itext7

I trying to convert from iText5 to iText7. Got the package for iText7 from Nuget.

Comment: Please be more specific about what functionality you're aiming to implement. iText7 was designed to be a lot more modular. So depending on your usecase there might be different classes that could serve your needs.

Answer (score 28):

That's explained in [chapter 5](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-5-manipulating-existing-pdf-document) of the [iText 7 Jump-start tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/). There is no `PdfStamper` class anymore. There is only a `PdfDocument` class that is used for creation of files *as well as* for manipulation of files.

Your question is very incomplete.

Is your code used to fill out forms? In that case, you need something like this:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(
    new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields();
fields.get("name").setValue("Abhishek Kumar");
pdf.close();
```

Or in C#:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
PdfFormField toSet;
fields.TryGetValue("name", out toSet);
toSet.SetValue("Abhishek Kumar");
form.FlattenFields();
pdf.Close();
```

Is your code used to add extra content to a document? In that case, you need something like this:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc =
    new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
Rectangle pageSize;
PdfCanvas canvas;
int n = pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages();
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    PdfPage page = pdfDoc.getPage(i);
    pageSize = page.getPageSize();
    canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    // add new content
}
pdfDoc.close();
```

Where it says `// add new content`, you can add content to the `canvas`.

Are you using `PdfStamper` for something else? In that case, you need to improve your question.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm trying to fill out form, fetching a template from database, filling it and then saving it in database. Though I'm getting syntax error on line Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields(); saying could not find namespace 'Map<,>'

Comment: I assumed that every C# developer was supposed to know the C# equivalent of a `Map` in Java. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the AcroForm hint, didn't found that one yet in their horrible documentations!